# Cannot get select value using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have select box with some values and using AJAX to send data to php and display those data inside `<div>` , Here is my code I don't know why this is not working.

When I used button to get value from  It was working. I have tried multiple tutorials and red a lot of question regarding AJAX and select box.

I tried making funciton and inside select calling it with `onchange`

**product.php**

```
<div id="input-option232">
<div class="checkbox">


<div class="custom-select" style="width: 200px">
<form method="get" name="rate">

<select name="rate2" id="rate2">

<option value="0">Broj Rata:</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
</select>
</form>
</div>

</div>
<div id="ratice"></div> // I WANT TO DISPLAY HERE
</div>
```

**aj-select.js**

```
$("#rate2").on('change', function() {
        var level = $('#rate2').val();
        if(level){
            $.ajax ({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'rate.php',
                data: 'rate='+level,
                success : function(data) {
                    $('#ratice').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

**rate.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['rate'])){
    echo $rate = $_GET['rate'];
}

?>
```

**select.js**

```
var x, i, j, selElmnt, a, b, c;
/*look for any elements with the class "custom-select":*/
x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
  /*for each element, create a new DIV that will act as the selected item:*/
  a = document.createElement("DIV");
  a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
  a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  x[i].appendChild(a);
  /*for each element, create a new DIV that will contain the option list:*/
  b = document.createElement("DIV");
  b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
  for (j = 0; j < selElmnt.length; j++) {
    /*for each option in the original select element,
    create a new DIV that will act as an option item:*/
    c = document.createElement("DIV");
    c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
    c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        /*when an item is clicked, update the original select box,
        and the selected item:*/
        var y, i, k, s, h;
        s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
        h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
        for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
          if (s.options[i].innerHTML === this.innerHTML) {
            s.selectedIndex = i;
            h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
            y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
            for (k = 0; k < y.length; k++) {
              y[k].removeAttribute("class");
            }
            this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
            break;
          }
        }
        h.click();
    });
    b.appendChild(c);
  }
  x[i].appendChild(b);
  a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      /*when the select box is clicked, close any other select boxes,
      and open/close the current select box:*/
      e.stopPropagation();
      closeAllSelect(this);
      this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
      this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
    });
}
function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
  /*a function that will close all select boxes in the document,
  except the current select box:*/
  var x, y, i, arrNo = [];
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
  y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    if (elmnt === y[i]) {
      arrNo.push(i);
    } else {
      y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
      x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
    }
  }
}
/*if the user clicks anywhere outside the select box,
then close all select boxes:*/
document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);
```

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
         body{font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif}
        .custom-select {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
}
.custom-select select {
  display: none; /*hide original SELECT element:*/
}
.select-selected {
  background-color: #f4a137;
}
/*style the arrow inside the select element:*/
.select-selected:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
}
/*point the arrow upwards when the select box is open (active):*/
.select-selected.select-arrow-active:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
  top: 7px;
}
/*style the items (options), including the selected item:*/
.select-items div,.select-selected {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}
/*style items (options):*/
.select-items {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f4a137;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}
/*hide the items when the select box is closed:*/
.select-hide {
  display: none;
}
.select-items div:hover, .same-as-selected {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
    </style>
```

Comment: `url: 'rate.php?rate='+level` try this edit without using data.

Comment: @SilentCoder not working

Comment: Okay... Remember when I asked if you used a plugin for a fancier `select`. It was exactly what I was asking. `select.js` creates some new DOM elements... So the user do not really interact with the select of your original markup.
--- 
I now try to recreate that... I just miss the styling for that plugin... If you can post it.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette edited

Comment: And you got your solution, friend ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... You use a plugin to obtain a "fancier" `select`...

That plugin creates some new DOM elements... So the user do not really interact with the select of your original markup. It is only used to create the new ones... Then hidden.

Here is what's created as siblings of your `<form>`:

```
<div class="custom-select" style="width: 200px">
  <form method="get" name="rate">

    <select name="rate2" id="rate2">

      <option value="0">Broj Rata:</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="11">11</option>
      <option value="12">12</option>
    </select>
  </form>
  <div class="select-selected">
    Broj Rata:
  </div>
  <div class="select-items select-hide">
    <div>Broj Rata:</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
    <div>11</div>
    <div>12</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So we now need to use another selector to capture the user interaction.

Replace:

```
$("#rate2").on('change', function() {
```

with

```
$("[name='rate']+.select-selected+.select-items").on("click",function(){
```

---

The `+` sign in the selector is an ["adjacent sibling selector"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors). It targets the last one **IF** it immediately follows the previous (as a sibling in DOM).

And that makes the trick here very well.

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/xyEQMQ?editors=1111)

Comment: SO exists exactly for that matter ;) Happy coding!

Comment: 1 more question :D. How can i send 1 more value to AJAX from page `product.php` that I am loading using php, but it's displaying on `product.php` page

Comment: Something like `data: {'rate':level, 'otherParam': otherVariable},` ? I'm not sure to get the *loading but displaying* part of your question.

Comment: Yeah i know that but problem is I don't have idea how to send it from product.php

Comment: Ha. Supose it is about $myValue. You can echo it in a JS variable: `var myJSvalue = "<?php echo $myValue; ?>";`. Don't forget the quotes around the PHP tags. You also can echo it directly in the Ajax part, if you wish: `data: {'rate':level, 'otherParam': "<?php echo $myValue; ?>"},`

Comment: Ho... But that is in an external .js file... I just remembered. So use a "global" variable. Since the Ajax part is inside a document ready... You should attach it to the window. So: `var window.myJSvalue = "<?php echo $myValue; ?>";` and use `window.myJSvalue` in the Ajax part. ;)

Comment: You have to echo it above the script tag that load the external .js file.

Comment: I just tought about something. I have `<span class="price">` and value inside that span is value i need to pass but without first letter witch is $. I am thinking about using getElement by ID. Could that work ?

Comment: If that is `span class="price">$100</span>`, it would be `var price = $(".price").html().replace("$","");`

Comment: Did it. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Change the value of the **data** property to object `data: {'rate':level}`

```
    $("#rate2").on('change', function() {
        var level = $('#rate2').val();
        if(level){
            $.ajax ({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'rate.php',
                data: {'rate':level},
                success : function(data) {
                    $('#ratice').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });


 <?php
    if(isset($_GET['rate'])){
       $rate = $_GET['rate'];
       echo $rate;
    }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try next modifications, and check the developer console for messages in order to get some debugging.

**aj-select.js**

```
$("#rate2").on('change', function()
{
    var level = $('#rate2').val();
    console.log("Selected level is : " + level);

    if (level < 0) return;

    $.ajax ({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'rate.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {'rate':level},
        success: function(data)
        {
            console.log("SUCCESS - data is: " + data);
            $('#ratice').html(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
           console.log("ERROR: " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

**rate.php**

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['rate']))
    {
        echo json_encode($_GET['rate']);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet is working, so the problem must be either on the ajax call or the php script itself. Check the Network pane on the DevTools to see what's being sent to the server.

```js
$("#rate2").on('change', function() {
  var level = $('#rate2').val();
  if (level) {
    $('#ratice').html(level);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="input-option232">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <div class="custom-select" style="width: 200px">
      <form method="get" name="rate">
        <select name="rate2" id="rate2">
          <option value="0">Broj Rata:</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          </select>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="ratice"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see. Nothing is sent to server on value change

Comment: @minion Is the parameter empty or there is no request at all?

Comment: In the change handler, a simple `console.log("Change");` did not show up.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette(problem was that class) I have another javascript managing clicks on selectbox(closing after click..), after removing `"custom-select"` it is working, I don't know why this happened  I need both js

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette yeah, I already suggested there's a syntax error somewere, because the snippet above works.

Comment: @minion are you calling `stopPropagation()` in that handler ?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette YES right now after deleting `class="custom-select"`

Comment: So that was not only CSS after all... Okay. So you found it! Bravo!

Comment: @minion add the code for the `custom-select` handler.

Comment: @msg Yes I am calling that, Can I still use another js for this styling and eventHandlers ?

Comment: @minion that's the problem. That code prevents other handlers from executing.

Comment: @minion Ok, I see. You can't just remove the `stopPropagation` call. The problem is that there isn't a `select` in there, you are interacting with a replacement element so the `select` doesn't get the event. You could either try to wire it up to trigger the event in code or go for a [pure css](https://codepen.io/ericrasch/pen/zjDBx) styling

Comment: @msg yeah i saw that i am indeed changing value of both select boxes, but AJAX is not called, I am now tring to get them connected somehow

Comment: @minion changing the value **does not** trigger a change event. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript)

Comment: @msg Do u suggest something ?

Comment: @minion I'd discard that piece of js and go for css. It could cause more problems down the line since apparently all variables are in global scope. Check the link in previous comment if you decide to go with js

Comment: @minion I think you could also bind your ajax call to `$('.select-items').click()` instead. That should work...